# Bash foreach loop

Tags: bash, foreach

I have an input (let's say a file).
On each line there is a file name.
How can I read this file and display the content for each one.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Something like this would do:

```
xargs cat <filenames.txt
```

The `xargs` program reads its standard input, and for each line of input runs the `cat` program with the input lines as argument(s).

If you really want to do this in a loop, you can:

```
for fn in `cat filenames.txt`; do
    echo "the next file is $fn"
    cat $fn
done
```

Comment: Both of these don't work when the filenames contain spaces.

Comment: @mivk you can escape the space

Answer (score 52):

"foreach" is not the name for bash.  It is simply "for".  You can do things in one line only like:

```
for fn in `cat filenames.txt`; do cat "$fn"; done
```

Reference: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bash-for-loop-one-line-command/

Answer (score 23):

Here is a `while` loop:

```
while read filename
do
    echo "Printing: $filename"
    cat "$filename"
done < filenames.txt
```

Comment: This should be best approach. You with to use the '-r' & '-d' option with `read`

Comment: Unlike most other answers here, this one actually works, even when file names contain spaces.

Answer (score 6):

If they all have the same extension (for example .jpg), you can use this:

```
for picture in  *.jpg ; do
    echo "the next file is $picture"
done
```

(This solution also works if the filename has spaces)

Comment: I think there are situations in which it is useful to surround `*.jpg` with quotes, IIRC: `for picture in "*.jpg";`...

Answer (score 5):

```
xargs --arg-file inputfile cat
```

This will output the filename followed by the file's contents:

```
xargs --arg-file inputfile -I % sh -c "echo %; cat %"
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably want to handle spaces in your file names, abhorrent though they are :-)

So I would opt initially for something like:

```
pax> cat qq.in
normalfile.txt
file with spaces.doc

pax> sed 's/ /\\ /g' qq.in | xargs -n 1 cat
<<contents of 'normalfile.txt'>>
<<contents of 'file with spaces.doc'>>

pax> _
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cat `cat filenames.txt`
```

will do the trick