# Add contents of 1 file to the top of another file

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, terminal, ed

I need to insert text from 1 file at the top of a large number of files in a directory and its subdirectories. I have been able to do this successfully on a file by file basis using ed:

```
ed -s FileToAddTo.txt <<< $'0r TextToAdd.txt\nw'
```

However, when I replace FileToAddTo.txt with *.txt, nothing happens. How can I modify this, or use another Unix command such as sed, to add the contents of TextToAdd.txt recursively to all files in a directory ending with a specific extension? e.g

```
ed -rs *.txt <<< $'0r TextToAdd.txt\nw'
```

Please note that the code above this line does not work, it merely demonstrates what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
cat TextToAdd.txt FileToAddTo.txt > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp FileToAddTo.txt
```

i.e. cat the new header file and the original file into a temporary file and then, if it was successful, rename the temporary file as the original.

And to run recursively !! PLEASE TEST ON BACKED UP DATA!!!

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c "cat TextToAdd.txt {} > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp {}" \;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work. When I replace filetoaddto.txt with *.txt nothing happens. Your second line of code does not even reference texttoadd.txt

Comment: I see what happened, sorry. I have updated it and there shouldn't be any need to change anything now. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

This works pretty well for me:

```
$ for fn in `find . -name '*.txt'`; do; cat textToAdd.txt $fn > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp $fn; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162821/bash-foreach-loop), you can try:

```
for fn in `ls -R /folderName`; do cat "$fn" >> fileName;  done
```

Comment: Will fail for file names containing white space and does the opposite of what the OP wants.