# Call script on all file names starting with string in folder bash

Tags: bash

I have a set of files I want to perform an action on in a folder that i'm hoping to write a scipt for. Each file starts with `mazeFilex` where `x` can vary from any number , is there a quick and easy way to perform an action on each file? e.g. I will be doing

`cat mazeFile0.txt | ./maze_ppm 5 | convert - maze0.jpg`

how can I select each file knowing the file will always start with `mazeFile`?

Comment: the filenames or the file contents do start with `mazeFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for fname in mazeFile*
do
    base=${fname%.txt}
    base=${base#mazeFile}
    ./maze_ppm 5 <"$fname" | convert - "maze${base}.jpg"
done
```

#### Notes

- `for fname in mazeFile*; do`

  This codes starts the loop.  Written this way, it is safe for all filenames, whether they have spaces, tabs or whatever in their names.
- `base=${fname%.txt}; base=${base#mazeFile}`

  This removes the `mazeFile` prefix and `.txt` suffix to just leave the base name that we will use for the output file.
- `./maze_ppm 5 <"$fname" | convert - "maze${base}.jpg"`

  The output filename is constructed using `base`.  Note also that `cat` was unnecessary and has been removed here.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in mazeFile*.txt ; do ./maze_ppm 5 <$i | convert - `basename maze${i:8} .txt`.jpg ; done
```

Comment: Doesn't account for mazeFile10.txt

Comment: @ClintPowell that's not true; try it by yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the ${i:8} was only getting the character at index 8. You're right technically, but mazeX.txt.jpg isn't the desired result either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to run through all the filenames.

```
#!/bin/bash
for fn in mazeFile*; do
    echo "the next file is $fn"
    # do something with file $fn
done
```

See answer here as well: [Bash foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162821/bash-foreach-loop)
I see you want a backreference to the number in the mazeFile. Thus I recommend **John1024**'s answer.

**Edit**: removes the unnecessary `ls` command, per @guido 's comment.

Comment: the ls command executed inside the for loop is absolutely useless. even worse, it can raise unexpected problems: http://superuser.com/questions/31464/looping-through-ls-results-in-bash-shell-script